# Char pointer pointing to string

Tags: c

can anyone explain why this code is not working, newbie here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * ptr = "hello";
    int i, cnt =0;
    while(ptr[i] != NULL)
    {
        i++;
        cnt++;

    } 
}
```

thanks !

Trying to understand that, ptr is pointing to array of character which is containing the hello as , 'h','e','l','l','o','\0'. am trying to get the length of it.

Comment: "Not working" as in will not compile? Always include the compiler messages when asking such questions.

Comment: Try initializing `i`.

Comment: When you do `i++` for the very first time, what is the initial value of `i`?

Comment: You are not assigning a value to i. you need i=0,cnt=0;

Comment: What is not working? How do you know that it's not working?

Comment: Don't forget to add `printf("%d\n", cnt);` at the end to print out the result, if what you want is to see it on the command line.

Comment: Also note that while the string termination character is called the "null" terminator, it's not the same as `NULL`. `NULL` is a null *pointer*. The null terminator character is `'\0'`.

Comment: As for the pointer `ptr`, it points to the first element of the array. The rest is pointer arithmetic: `ptr[i]` is the same as `*(ptr + i)`. So `ptr[0]` is the character at index `0` (the first character), `ptr[1]` is the character at index `1` (the second character), etc.

Comment: Yes it is not compilling, getting this error , test_charptr.c:8:18: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     while(ptr[i] != NULL)

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is that you think `int i, cnt = 0;` will initialize *both* `i` and `cnt` to zero? That's not correct (as hinted to by me and others). `int i, cnt = 0;` is equivalent to `int i; int cnt = 0;`. In other words, it leaves `i` uninitialized and with an indeterminate value.

Comment: Oh, and after the loop, both `i` and `cnt` will have the same value (when you initialize `i` to zero). There's no need for two separate variables.

Comment: Please copy-paste (as text) the *full* and *complete* build log into the question itself.

Comment: @Vin37 `while(ptr[cnt]) cnt++;`

Comment: Oh on a totally different note, because it's not allowed to modify literal strings it's recommended to use `const char *` to point to them. As in `const char * ptr = "hello";`

Comment: Also confusing is that the ASCII  character '\0' is named NUL.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a decent compiler and have at it configured correctly ([What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)) then you will get a compiler error:

> error: comparison between pointer and integer

Because `ptr[i]` (a `char`) is an integer type, but `NULL` may be a pointer type.

C has some confusing terminology. *Null pointers* and *null termination* sound similar but are quite different, unrelated things.

- A null pointer is a pointer pointing at a well-defined nowhere.
- You can turn a pointer into a null pointer by assigning it a *null pointer constant*. `NULL` is such a null pointer constant.
- A character string ending with a zero is said to be null terminated. That is, a proper C string. Despite the name, this has nothing to do with null pointers.

Because of the similar sounding and confusing names, null termination is sometimes spelled "NUL" with a single L, to make it distinct from null pointers.

When we want to write self-documenting code expressing a null termination character, the standard way to do that in C is through a so-called "octal escape sequence": `'\0'`. This has the value zero but the peculiar octal notation makes it stand out.

So the correct fix is: `while(ptr[i] != '\0')`

---

Furthermore, you did not initialize the variable `i` to zero, which is another bug. When declaring multiple variables on a single line like `int i, cnt =0;`, only the one next to the `=` gets assigned the initialized value, not both of them. Which is one reason why declaring multiple variables on the same line is considered bad practice, always to be avoided.

---

A complete rewrite into something more correct and possibly more readable would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* ptr = "hello";
    int cnt=0;

    for(int i=0; ptr[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        cnt++;
    } 
    printf("%d\n", cnt);
}
```

(If `i` is declared outside the loop we could as well use `i` instead of `cnt`, since it too will have the value 5 when the loop is done.)

Comment: Or just `int cnt=0; while(ptr[cnt] != '\0') { ++cnt; }`  to avoid `i`

Comment: NUL was the official name for the null byte in the ASCII code set.  The control characters (value less than 32) all had names with 2 or 3 characters: NUL, SOH, STX, ETX, EOT, ENQ, BEL, BS, HT, LF, VT, FF, CR, SO, SI, DLE, DC1, DC2, DC3, DC4, NAK, SYN, ETB, CA, EM, SUB, ESC, FS, GS, RS, US.  And character 127 is DEL.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* ptr = "hello";
    int cnt=0;

    for(int i=0; ptr[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        cnt++;
    } 
    printf("%d\n", cnt);
}
```

Comment: This code is certainly an improvement over the OP's, but would you care to offer an actual explanation? Code-only answers are poorly regarded here.  Also, the code presented appears to be character-for-character identical to that presented in @Lundin's answer.  It's short enough that the two of you might have come to the same thing independently, but it's suspicious.  Overall, this doesn't seem to add anything new relative to the other, hours earlier, answer.